# The table can not be centered

Tags: longtable

I have a table in the thesis that is too long and has too much information, when I finished, the position of the table is to the right side of the page, not centred. How can I make it centre in the page? Here is the code, with shortened information in the table. In the file it looks like this, the table can not be centered. Could anyone help me?
(I did not specify specific font size. The code below can be run in overleaf)

You can download the small file via this link:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fJmBBQvIpI4tMdQ2nqrnDbg9cJKPK2X8/view?usp=drive_link

[image]

```
 \documentclass{report}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
 \usepackage{setspace}% for\doublespacing
 \usepackage{indentfirst}% for indent the first line
 \usepackage{longtable}
 \usepackage{textalpha}
  \usepackage{ragged2e}


  \begin{document}
  \begin{longtable}[c]{| c | c |c | c |c | }
  \caption{\centering DUSP Protein or RNA expression in animal and human 
     brain\label{long3}}\\
  \hline
   \multicolumn{5}{| c |}{ DUSP Protein or RNA expression in animal and 
     human brain }\\
  \hline
     Isoforms   & Expression&   Protein/ mRNA   & Species&  Ref.\\
 \hline
 \endfirsthead
 \hline
  \multicolumn{5}{|c|}{Continuation of Table \ref{long3}}\\
  \hline
   Isoforms  & Expression&   Protein/ mRNA   & Species&  Ref.\\
\hline
 \endhead
 \hline
 \endfoot
 \hline
  \multicolumn{5}{| c |}{End of Table}\\
  \hline\hline
  \endlastfoot
 SSH2    &   Brain  &mRNA&   Mice&   [4]\\
    & Thalamus &     &      &   \\
    & Hippocampus &     &      &   \\
 SSH3     & Hippocampus  &mRNA& Human&[5]\\
     & Temporal gyrus &     &      &   \\
    & Frontal gyrus    &       &     &     \\
    &Prefrontal cortex& mRNA&   Mice&   [6]\\
   & Hypothalamus &       &     &     \\
   &Amygdala&   mRNA&   Mice&   [7]\\
   SSH1 & Frontal cortex  & Protein & Human & 
      \cite{Barone2014InactivationGamma-secretase,Zafar2017Cytoskeleton- 
             AssociatedDisease}\\
  & Cerebellum &     &     &    \\     
        & Primary cortical neurons& Protein&    Mice& 
     \cite{Barone2014InactivationGamma-secretase}\\
        & Ganglion neurons  &Protein& 
              Chick&\cite{Endo2003ControlCofilin}\\
     SSH2    &  Brain  &mRNA&   Mice&   [4]\\
            & Thalamus &     &      &   \\
            & Hippocampus &     &      &   \\
      SSH3     & Hippocampus    &mRNA& Human&[5]\\
     & Temporal gyrus &     &      &   \\
     & Frontal gyrus    &       &     &     \\
      &Prefrontal cortex&   mRNA&   Mice&   [6]\\
      & Hypothalamus &       &     &     \\
     &Amygdala& mRNA&   Mice&   [7]\\
        PRL2      & Cerebellum &    mRNA &  Human   &[8]\\
      & Cerebral cortex  &       &     &     \\
      &Neuronal lineages &  mRNA    &Zebrafish& [9]\\
     CDC14A    &    Cortical slices&    mRNA&   Human&  [10]\\
      & Cerebral cortex&    Protein &Human  & *[11] \\
    hCDC14Bpar& Adult/fetal brain & mRNA&   Human & [12]\\
      hCDC14B1 & Hippocampus& mRNA & Human &[12]\\
    & Prefrontal cortex &       &     &     \\
    & Amygdala   &      &    &     \\
    & Hypothalamus &      &    &     \\
    
     hCDC14B2& Hippocampus& mRNA& Human& [12]\\
     & Prefrontal cortex&      &    &     \\

    & Amygdala       &         &    &   \\
    & Hypothalamus   &         &    &   \\
        hCDC14B3 & Hippocampus  &mRNA&Human&[12]\\
       & Prefrontal cortex &    &    &   \\
       & Amygdala     &         &     &    \\
       & Hypothalamus  &         &     &    \\
   hCDC14C & Adult brain   &    mRNA&Human& [12]\\
     &  Embryonic forebrain,&  &  & \\
     & Dorsal telencephalon    &      &      &    \\
        PTENs    &  Cerebral cortex, &  Protein& Human& *[11]\\
     & Cerebellum&     &      &      \\
     & Hippocampus&     &      &      \\
     & Anterior olfactory nucleus   &  Protein&  Rat&[13]\\
     & Cerebral cortex &     &      &      \\ 
     & Amygdaloid nucleus &     &      &      \\
     & Hippocampus &     &      &      \\
     & Purkinje's cells&     &      &      \\
     & Basal ganglia&     &      &      \\
     &Thalamus&     &      &      \\
     & Midbrain, Pons&     &      &      \\
     &Ventral prefrontal cortex&    Protein&    Human&  [14]\\
     &Layer III temporal cortex &   Protein&    Human&  [15]\\
     &Frontal cortex    & Protein & Human & [16]\\
     Myotubularin & Spinal cord &   mRNA&   Human&  [17]\\
        & Substantia nigra&     &      &      \\
     & Cerebral cortex & Protein & Human &*[11]\\
     & Hippocampus  &     &      &      \\
     & Cerebellum &     &      &      \\
       MKP1 &Hippocampus&   Protein/mRNA&   Human/Mice  &[18]\\
        (DUSP1)&    Caudate&    mRNA&   Human&  [19]\\
  &Temporal cortex& Protein&    Human&  [20]\\
 & Cerebral cortex &    Protein&    Human&  [21]\\
 & Cerebellum &     &      &      \\
 &Striatum  & mRNA  & Mice&     [19]\\
 &Striatum&  mRNA&  Rat&    [22]\\
 &Thalamus/Cortex&     &      &      \\ 
 & Neocortex    &Protein& Rat&[24]\\
 & BNST &     &      &      \\
         MKP2 & Cerebellar vermis&  Protein&    Human&  [25]\\
     (DUSP4)    &Cortex  &Protein&Human &[21]\\
    & Hippocampus&     &      &      \\
    & Cerebellum &     &      &      \\
    &The medial prefrontal cortex &     mRNA& Rat& [26]\\
    &Lateral frontal cortex &     &      &      \\
    &Parietal cortex&     &      &      \\
    &Hippocampus&     &      &      \\
       MKP3 & The medial prefrontal cortex  &mRNA&Rat&[26]\\
      (DUSP6)&    Lateral frontal cortex &     &      &      \\
   &  Parietal cortex&     &      &      \\
   &  Hippocampus&     &      &      \\
   &Ventromedial PFC&   mRNA&   Human/Mice&     [27]\\
   &Striatum & mRNA&    Rat&    [22]\\
   &Cortex&     &      &      \\
   &Hippocampus&     &      &      \\
      PAC1   & Hippocampus & Protein/mRNA & Mice &[28] \\
       (DUSP2) & Hippocampus&   mRNA    & Human&    [18]\\
      Hvhr3 & Brain (not specified)& mRNA &Mice & [29]\\
    (DUSP5)& Nucleus accumbens& mRNA&   Mice&   [30]\\
   & Medial prefrontal cortex&  mRNA    &Rat&   [31]\\
   MKP-X & Whole-brain& mRNA  &Mice& [32]\\
          ( DUSP7)& &     &      &      \\
    Hvh5  & Amygdala    &   mRNA&   Human&   [33]\\
   (DUSP8) & caudate nucleus&     &      &      \\
    & Corpus callosum&     &      &      \\
    & Hippocampus&     &      &      \\
    & Hypothalamus/thalamus&     &      &      \\
    & Subthalamic nucleus&     &      &      \\
    & Substantia nigra&     &      &      \\
      MTMR2 & Cortex &Protein/mRNA & Rat &[34]\\
   & Hippocampus&     &      &      \\
   & Cerebellum&     &      &      \\
       MTMR5 & Brain    &Protein&   Mice&   [35]\\
  & The sciatic nerve&     &      &      \\
       Laforin & Cerebellum &   mRNA & Mice & [36]\\
          (EPM2A) & Hippocampus&     &      &      \\
    & Cerebral cortex&     &      &      \\
    & Olfactory bulb&     &      &      \\
         DUSP12 &   Hippocampus & mRNA  & Human & [18]\\
      DUSP14 & Retinal ganglion cells   &mRNA&  Rat&    [37]\\
      DUSP15&   Schwann cell&   mRNA&   Rat&    [38]\\
  & Myelinating Oligodendrocytes&   mRNA&   Rat&    [39]\\
      DUSP18 &  Fetal brain &mRNA   &Human& [40]\\
      DUSP19 &  Hippocampus&    mRNA    &Human& [18]\\
   &Ventral subiculum&  mRNA    &Human& [27]\\
     DUSP22 & Hippocampus & Protein  &Human  &[41]\\
      DUSP23&   Nucleus accumbens&mRNA&Human&[27]\\
 & The Broadman area&     &      &      \\
      DUSP26&   Hippocampus&    Protein/mRNA    & Human&    [18, 42]\\

   \end{longtable}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. It looks like the `longtable` environment might be wider than the text block. Please tell us which document class and which main font size you employ and how wide the text block is -- or, equivalently, how wide the margins are.

Comment: Welcome. // Please try your posted code, if it compiles. If not, please add the missing lines, until it does and edit your post. Thank you

Comment: Please extend your code fragment to complete small document {MWE: Minimal Working Example) Which reproduce your problem and which we can compile as it is.

Comment: Table, produced by your table code fragment is nicely centered in the text block, So, please provide complete small document (MWE) which reproduce your problem

Comment: Here is the file link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fJmBBQvIpI4tMdQ2nqrnDbg9cJKPK2X8/view?usp=drive_link

Comment: You haven't granted access to the file on googledrive.

Comment: do not use external links, edit the example in the question so it shows the problem

Comment: If this is for a thesis, it doesn't mattter if it is centered.  It will still violate the margins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that the table is simply too wide to fit inside the text block. I suggest that you switch from a `longtable` environnent to an `xltabular` environment, set the table's target width of `\textwidth`, and allow automatic line breaking in at least one of the columns.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
%%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % <-- new
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{textalpha}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

% new code
\usepackage{xltabular} 
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X} % suspend full justification
% special new column type for header row:
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}%
    p{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth\relax}}

\begin{document}

\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{ | l | L | c | l | l | } % <-- new

%% headers and footers
\caption{DUSP Protein or RNA expression in animal and human brain\label{long3}}\\
\hline
\multicolumn{5}{ | C | }{DUSP Protein or RNA expression in animal and human brain}\\
\hline
Isoforms & Expression & Protein/mRNA & Species & Ref. \\
\hline
\endfirsthead
 
\hline
\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{Continuation of Table \ref{long3}}\\
\hline
Isoforms & Expression & Protein/mRNA & Species & Ref. \\
\hline
\endhead
 
\hline
\endfoot
 
\hline
\multicolumn{5}{| c |}{End of Table}\\
\hline\hline
\endlastfoot

%% body of table
SSH2    & Brain            & mRNA  & Mice  & [104, 105] \\
        & Thalamus         &       &       & \\
        & %Hippocampus 
          Primary cortical neurons & &     & \\
SSH3    & Hippocampus      & mRNA  & Human & [5] \\
        & Temporal gyrus   &       &       & \\
        & Frontal gyrus    &       &       & \\
        & Prefrontal cortex& mRNA  & Mice  & [6] \\
        & Hypothalamus     &       &       & \\
        & Amygdala         & mRNA  & Mice  & [7] \\
        
\end{xltabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! It works. I thought long table fit my much information and it doesn't work as I thought. Your solution is perfect! Thanks again.